# IIS7: Using Authorization for Static Content in Classic Pipeline Mode

Tags: iis-7

I have to protect some static files on my web-server, so that only logged in users are able to see it. The application running on the server can only run in "Classic"-Pipeline Mode.

All other answers either explane how to do it with [integrated pipeline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903292/how-do-i-protect-static-files-with-asp-net-form-auhentication-on-iis-7-5) or with [IIS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27821856/deny-static-content-for-unauthorized-users-using-web-config).

I have tried to adapt the IIS6 solution, adding a new mapping to the ISAPI Handler for all files, but this seems to have no effect.

Is it possible to use the standard authorization for this?